# Find and replace a pattern after last space

Tags: bash, awk, sed, pattern-matching

I need to replace any matching pattern after the last space. I've an ssh certificate file like:

```
ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com 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 ssh_host_rsa_key.pub
```

Here, at the end of the file I've `ssh_host_rsa_key.pub` or it can be something different like `/home/user/ssh_host_rsa_key.pub`. I want to find it and replace by another string.

How can I find and replace everything starting from last space? With `sed` or `awk` or anything else...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it guaranteed that the comment at the end of the line never contains any spaces?

Comment: I tried with different files containing one empty line and no empty lines. Following codes worked:

`sed 's/ [^ ]*$/ new text/' < file` 
and
`sed -E 's/(^.*) [^ ]+$/\1 replacement_text/' file.txt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try

```
sed -E 's/(^.*) [^ ]+$/\1 replacement_text/' file.txt
```

This will match

- "anything from the start of the line" (the `^.*` pattern, placed in a "capture group" `( ... )`),
- then a space,
- and then "anything *but* a space (`[^ ]`) up to the end of the line" (the `+` behind the `[...]` means "one or more such characters", and the `$` is an anchor that indicates "end-of-line"),

and replace the latter part with your replacement text. The former part is replaced "with itself" thanks to the capture group `\1`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.
`sed -E 's/(^.*) [^ ]+$/\1 replacement_text/' file.txt` works.

Comment: @mufit You're welcome. If you found any of the answers useful, please consider [accepting](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) one of them so that others facing a similar problem may find it more easily.

Answer (score 1):

This works when there are two space delimited fields at the start of the line. The third field is allowed to be absent.

```
awk '{print $1 " " $2 " new text"}' < file
```

This replaces after the *last space* no matter how many spaces there are in the line:

```
sed 's/ [^ ]*$/ new text/' < file
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Second command worked perfectly.
`sed 's/ [^ ]*$/ new text/' < file`